# Prevent data loss while upgrading Kafka with a single broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Kafka server which runs on a single node. There is only 1 node because it's a test server. But even for a test server, I need to be sure that no data loss will occur while upgrade is in process.

I upgrade Kafka as:

1. Stop Kafka, Zookeeper, Kafka Connect and Schema Registry.
2. Upgrade all the components.
3. Start upgraded services.

Data loss may occur in the first step, where kafka is not running. I guess you can do a rolling update (?) with multiple brokers to prevent data loss but in my case it is not possible. How can I do something similar with a single broker? Is it possible? If not, what is the best approach for upgrading?

Comment: Why are you only running one broker? If the data is important enough not to lose during upgrade, it's presumably important enough not to lose if that one broker failed during normal operation too.

Comment: It's a test environment, my company uses only one broker for that. Data loss is somehow tolerable but it's better if no data will be lost. Should I request another server for that? @RobinMoffatt

Comment: There's two things to consider. Firstly, what is the tolerance for data loss? A single broker leaves you exposed. Three at a minimum with appropriate replication factors set on the topics is a good idea. Second, is the purpose of the test environment to mimic production? Because being able to practice upgrades is a perfect example where you'd want similar environment on which to test first. Second point is less a factor if it's just a dev sandbox and you have pre-prod elsewhere already.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, obviously, you are always vulnerable to data losses if you are using only one node.

If you can't have more nodes you have the only choice:

1. Stop producing;
2. Stop consuming;
3. Enable parameter `controlled.shutdown.enable` - this will ensure that your broker saved offset in case of a shutdown.
   I guess the first 2 steps are quite tricky.

Unfortunately, there is not much to play with - Kafka was not designed to be fault-tolerant with only one node.

Answer (score 0):

The process of a rolling upgrade is still the same for a single broker.

Existing data during the upgrade shouldn't be lost.

Obviously, if producers are still running, all their requests will be denied while the broker is down, thus why you not only need multiple brokers to prevent data-loss, but a *balanced cluster* (with unclean leader election disabled) where your restart cycles don't completely take a set of topics offline.